# rxPredict throws SQL Server does not exist or access denied error

Tags: sql-server, r

I am trying out the SQL Server R services tutorial on MSDN - link below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt629164.aspx

When I run the rxPredict command:

```
rxPredict(modelObject = logitObj, 
           data = featureDataSource, 
           outData = scoredOutput, 
           predVarNames = "Score", 
           type = "response",
           writeModelVars = TRUE, 
           overwrite = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> ======  SG01NB-4300092  ( process  1 ) has started run at  2016-07-04 09:43:35.00  ====== 
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. 
> Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 5682. ThreadID: 13560 Rethrowing. 
> Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 5249. ThreadID: 13560 Rethrowing. 
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Connection not open 
>
> ODBC Error in SQLDisconnect 
> Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. 
> Calls: source ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> doTryCatch -> .Call 
>
> Execution halted 
>
> Error in rxCompleteClusterJob(hpcServerJob, consoleOutput, autoCleanup) : 
>   No results available - final job state: failed
> ```

I have made sure that my rxSetComputeContext(cc) is using a valid user login that can create tables. I am also installing SQL Server on the local machine I am working on so it cannot be a network issue.

Has anyone encountered this issue and manage to run this statement successfully?

Thanks for any replies and help!

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem lies with outData = scoredOutput statement. If I set the outData=NULL and change the server context to local, I am able to generate an output from rxPredict.

What I decided was to then execute the rxPredict with the rxSetComputeContext("local") get the output data frame (outDF) and then save it back to the SQL Server using rxDataStep(inData = outDF, outFile = scoredOutput, overwrite=TRUE)

```
rxSetComputeContext("local")

fds <- rxImport(featureDataSource)

outDF <- structure(list(Score = numeric(),
                        tipped = integer(),
                        passenger_count = numeric(),
                        trip_distance = numeric(),
                        trip_time_in_secs = numeric(),
                        direct_distance = numeric()), 
                   class = "data.frame")

outDF <- rxPredict(modelObject = logitObj, data = fds, outData = NULL, 
          predVarNames = "Score", type = "response",
          writeModelVars = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)  

# reset the compute context to the server and persist the df result to the table
rxSetComputeContext(cc)

rxDataStep(inData = outDF, outFile = scoredOutput, overwrite=TRUE)
```

If anyone has a better approach please share and let me know!

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have provided the worker/Launchpad accounts (that are used for running the R scripts) permissions to login to SQL Server on your behalf. See [Enable Implied Authentication for Launchpad Accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx#Anchor_2) for more details.

Comment: @ArunGurunathan, I get this error even after enabling Implied Authentication. The problem, I think, is not with connecting remotely - because I can query, get summary statistics, even build linear and logistic regression models in the SQL compute context; but the error is thrown only when using rxPredict. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your SQL Server running locally or on remote server or the cloud? Can you share the full error message/script?

Comment: My SQL Server is on the cloud (Azure). The script and error are pretty much the same as in this question.

Comment: For SQL Server R Services in Azure VM, please make sure you have set up the protocols for TCP/IP & named pipe as per Installing SQL Server R Services on an Azure Virtual Machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt748179(SQL.130).aspx) document

Comment: Thanks @ArunGurunathan. Does this (image below) mean that named pipes and TCP/IP protocols are enabled? 

[SQL Server 2016 Configuration Manager Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Bolyk2a.png)

Comment: Can you check under "SQL Server Network Configuration" and ensure Protocols for your SQL instance is enabled?

Comment: Yes, they are enabled. Thanks for the help. I've disabled a rule that blocked access to R local accounts in the firewall, and that helped my script run. But thanks for all these tips too.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this error for a long time now. The weird part is that the script runs on one of my SQL Server 2016 VMs but not the other. So I compared the properties of both the servers and made sure I hadn't forgotten some post-installation procedure.

Thanks in part to @ArunGurunathan,  I found an anomaly while looking for these variances. Opening the SQL Server machine itself, and looking at the firewall settings - I found that there was a rule that blocked network access to R local user accounts. I disabled that rule, and my script (rxPredict) ran without any errors.

Try and let me know if it works for you.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what version of SQL Server you are running (e.g. from running `PRINT @@VERSION` command from SSMS)?

Please note turning off the firewall rule to allow R process to talk over network has potential for security issues and is not recommended in production scenarios.

Comment: @ArunGurunathan, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64>. 

Also, thanks a lot for the tip. So, disabling that firewall rule is only a workaround, and not the fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue success & error msgs:
[image]

The outData method was not permissioned to write to the SQL DB,
but fixed it by enabling the SQLRUser **Group** with write access to the DB in question.

Fix applied
[image]

Basically you are Enabling Implied Authentication for Launchpad Accounts

Specifically navigate to the User Account from the Control Panel and you'll see the SQLR UserGroup with 20 accounts.

Permission these on the Server and DB Table with write access.

That should see you right. Good luck

Comment: Enable Implied Authentication for Launchpad Accounts

Specifically navigate to the User Account from the Control Panel and you'll see the SQLR UserGroup with 20 accounts.

Permission these on the Server and DB Table with write access.

That should see you right. Good luck