# rxPredict Error while using set compute context

Tags: r, sql-server

When I am trying out the SQL Server R services tutorial to set the compute context and predict the score I am getting the below error.

Link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/deepdive-score-new-data

When I run the rxPredict command:

```
outDF<-rxPredict(modelObject = logitModel, data =data_train , outData = 
scoredOutput, predVarNames = "Score", type = "response",writeModelVars = 
TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
======  XXXX  ( process  1 ) has started run at  2018-03-21 17:03:53.93  ======

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 
'XXXX\MSSQLSERVE1'.


Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 5682. ThreadID: 22272 
Rethrowing. 
Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 5249. ThreadID: 22272 
Rethrowing.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Connection not open



ODBC Error in SQLDisconnect 
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 
'XXXX\MSSQLSERVE1'.

Calls: source ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> doTryCatch -> 
.Call 
Execution halted 
Error in rxCompleteClusterJob(hpcServerJob, consoleOutput, autoCleanup) : 
No results available - final job state: failed
implicit list embedding of S4 objects is deprecated</i>
```

And I have already used the below link but even I am getting the same error:

[rxPredict throws SQL Server does not exist or access denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176135/rxpredict-throws-sql-server-does-not-exist-or-access-denied-error/38213975)

And I have made sure that my rxSetComputeContext(cc) is using a valid user login that can create table. Also ,I am using my local SQL Server machine I am working on, so it cannot be a network issue.

Is there any permissions that I need to change before performing rxpredict command ?

Has anyone encountered this issue and manage to run this statement successfully?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: The error you are getting is `Login failed for user 'XXXX\MSSQLSERVE1'` which is not the same errors as the post you linked. Are you sure you have the ODBC connection configured correctly? Like, that instance is spelled correctly and the user name and password are valid?

Comment: Here instance,user name and password are valid and I was able to perform the model (rxlogit) ,but I cant perform the predictions for the model. So, can you suggest where it is going wrong ??